# How to ask for user input for location or hardcode a lat/long pair, if users select "Dont Allow" in mkmapview?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview

(apologies if it seems like a rookie question but I work for a startup & given the stage where we are, I can use all the help to move things fwd .. thx guys!)

I am building a map based iOS app wherein its good to have user's location but not mandatory.

If the user selects "Don't Allow"  for sharing his location, then I want to either have the map take him to a hardcoded lat/long pair OR I can show him dropdowns to pick his location but then it just does not drop the marker.

There has to be someway in which iOS app developers want to use maps but dont mandated detcting user's location .. How does one do that (if at all that's posible)?

Comment: What is your exact question?  What's the exact problem?  Yes, you can use a map without having user location.  What does "but then it just does not drop the marker" mean -- what happens, what error, etc?  Also, why do you have both Google and MKMapView tags?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at CLLocationManager class.. you can always check the Authorization status of the user loacation choice using `+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus` of CLLocationManager class.. Based on that you can decide your other actions like sending a hardcoded location value to someone or not.